# SSL alert number 40 in apache bench on mac

Tags: ssl, openssl, apachebench

When I'm trying to use apache bench from Mac OS X 10.10 for [my website](https://kubog.ru) I'm always getting the same error on any request:
`6979:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 40
SSL handshake failed (1).`

I can get the same error using `-f SSL3` option on any other website not supporting SSL3, but on this website I get this error even if I set `-f TLS1.2`. Qualys SSL Labs test reports that SSL3 isn't supported, and TLS is supported. And in any Linux OS everything works great. I have free SSL certificate from StartCom.

How to get rid of this error?

Thank you!